# Please help me understand Flux.join parameters

Tags: java, project-reactor

I have two fluxes of timestamped events that are emitted at different rates, and I would like to combine these into a single composite flux based on their overlapping time windows. This seems like a textbook use for Flux.join, but I can't work out what to supply for a couple of the parameters. According to the [JavaDocs](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#join-org.reactivestreams.Publisher-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BiFunction-), the parameters are:

- `other` - the other Publisher to correlate items with
- `leftEnd` - a function that returns a Publisher whose emissions indicate the time window for the source value to be considered
- `rightEnd` - a function that returns a Publisher whose emissions indicate the time window for the right Publisher value to be considered
- `resultSelector` - a function that takes an item emitted by each Publisher and returns the value to be emitted by the resulting Flux

I understand that `other` is the second flux to join to and that `resultSelector` is function that combines a single value from each flux into the result or aggregate value to output on the new flux. But I can't get my head around `leftEnd` and `rightEnd`. Their purpose must be to enable the join operator to determine which values from the 2 fluxes overlap in time. But why must these functions return Publishers and how can it be that the 2 Publishers can have different value types? Naively, I would have expected to have to produce a function for each input flux that extracts the timestamp or time period for each value together with a comparator that can determine if they overlap, so obviously there is something I am not "getting" about this.

An example is probably in order. Let's just assume that the 2 input fluxes have the same value types consisting of a String and a time period denoted by a beginTime and endTime that are both long milliseconds, i.e.

```
class ValueClass {
    String text;
    long beginTime;
    long endTime;
}
```

For simplicity, I will write values as {"A", 0, 250}, denoting a ValueClass object with text="A", beginTime=0, and endTime=250. Now let's say the 2 input fluxes produce the following values:

```
leftFlux: {"A", 0, 249}, {"B", 250, 499}, {"C", 500, 749}, {"D", 750, 999}
rightFlux: {"X", 0, 333}, {"Y", 334, 666}, {"Z", 667, 999}
```

On a timeline, I could visualize this roughly as follows:

```
A   B   C   D
X     Y    Z
```

Based on this, I expect the joined flux to produce the string values:

```
"AX", "BX", "BY", "CY", "CZ", "DZ".
```

The code to accomplish this should be similar to:

```
leftFlux.join(
    rightFlux,
    new Function<ValueClass, Publisher<something>>() {
            @Override
            public Publisher<something> apply(ValueClass v) {
                return some-publisher;
            }
        },
    new Function<ValueClass, Publisher<something>>() {
            @Override
            public Publisher<something> apply(ValueClass v) {
                return some-publisher;
            }
        },
    new BiFunction<ValueClass, ValueClass, String>() {
        public String apply(ValueClass l, ValueClass r) {
            return l.text + r.text;
        }
    }
);
```

Which value types ("something" in the code above) should the Publishers be? And which values should those publishers produce?

---

**Update**

Even after looking at the (sadly few) test cases that are included in Reactor Core, I have been unable to understand how Flux.join is intended to be used. I have, however, found a different solution for my case. I have built a class that subscribes to the two fluxes using inner classes, puts their items in explicit queues, which are then processed step by step and produce result items via a DirectProcessor.